# Matlab: Converting a string to a rational number

Tags: string, matlab

How to convert the rational number strings to numbers from a text file having musical notes listed with names and timings.

For instance;

```
La,1/8 
La,1/8 
La,1/8 
La,1/8 
Si,1/4
```

Reading the file into Matlab and get the lines one by one.

```
fid=fopen('file.txt');
while 1
  tline = fgetl(fid);
  if ~ischar(tline), break, end
  %disp(tline)
  split = strsplit(tline,',');
  note=split(1);
  timing=str2num(split(2));
end
fclose(fid);
```

I can get the first data which is the musical note as string. The problem is the timing part. str2num can convert strings to numbers but when it's a rational number as in the example above, it returns NaN.
How to get these data, the first one as string and the second as rational number?

Comment: I assume you mean "floating point number" (0.125), not [rational number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number) (1/8)?

Comment: No, rational number is exactly what I meant. I want it to be converted as 1/8 as a number.

Comment: You'll need to use symbolic math (e.g., `sym('1/8')`) or save the numerator and denominator separately (see `rat` and `rats`) then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that [`strsplit`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) returns a *cell array* of strings:

```
>> tline = 'La,1/8'; %// example line
>> split = strsplit(tline,',')
split = 
    'La'    '1/8'
```

and you can't apply [`str2num`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html) on a cell:

```
>> str2num(split(2))
Error using str2num (line 32)
Requires string or character array input.
```

But you can apply it on the cell's *contents*, which is a string:

```
>> str2num(split{2})
ans =
   0.125000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Another approach to consider (less low-level file manipulation)

If you have a file `music.txt` that's a csv:

```
Note, Timing
La, 1/8
Si, 1/4
```

You could read it into a Matlab [table](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html?refresh=true) and convert to your timing column to a double with:

```
t         = readtable('music.txt');
t.TimeNum = cellfun(@str2num, t.Timing); % Apply str2num to each entry 
                                         % of t.Timing cell array
```

Then your table `t` would be:

```
  Note    Timing    TimeNum 
  ____    ______    _____

  'La'    '1/8'      0.125
  'Si'    '1/4'      0.25
```